# Getting issue at the time of pod installation of cocoa pods-keys

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am getting error at the time of pod installation.
Error ==> [!] Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-keys` be installed. Please install it and try installation again.

I had installed cocoapods-keys and also updated cocoapods.

Podfile

```
#set platform
platform :ios, '12.1'
#insert your project and target name here
plugin 'cocoapods-keys', {
  :keys => [
    "KEYPARAM"
  ]}

target '[Project Name]' do
 
  # Pods
pod 'PodName', :git => 'link'

end
```

Comment: https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-keys/issues/198#issuecomment-828129528
 - This worked for me

Comment: If the problem is solved, then please either delete the question or answer it yourself. Do not leave it hanging.